# "Missing credentials in config" while trying to stream a file to Amazon S3 bucket in node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to setup a basic file stream to Amazon S3.
I copied and pasted the example on
https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-upload-stream

And modified it slightly (as attached).

```
   var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
   zlib = require('zlib'),
   s = require('fs');
   s3Stream = require('s3-upload-stream')(new AWS.S3()),

        // Set the client to be used for the upload.
        AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');


    // Create the streams
    var read = fs.createReadStream('path to a file');
    var compress = zlib.createGzip();
    var upload = s3Stream.upload({
        "Bucket": "bucketName",
        "Key": "file.txt"
    });

    module.exports = function (router) {
        router.get('/', function (req, res) {
            res.render('upload')
        })
        router.post('/', function (req, res) {
            // Handle errors.
            upload.on('error', function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });


            /* Handle progress. Example details object:
             { ETag: '"f9ef956c83756a80ad62f54ae5e7d34b"',
             PartNumber: 5,
             receivedSize: 29671068,
             uploadedSize: 29671068 }
             */
            upload.on('part', function (details) {
                console.log(details);
            });


            /* Handle upload completion. Example details object:
             { Location: 'https://bucketName.s3.amazonaws.com/filename.ext',
             Bucket: 'bucketName',
             Key: 'filename.ext',
             ETag: '"bf2acbedf84207d696c8da7dbb205b9f-5"' }
             */
            upload.on('uploaded', function (details) {
                console.log(details);
            });

            // Pipe the incoming filestream through compression, and up to S3.
            read.pipe(compress).pipe(upload);

        })

    }
```

My config file is setup like so:

```
{
 "accessKeyId": "key",
 "secretAccessKey":"secret",
 "region": "us-east-1e"
}
```

The code returns the following error:

```
    Failed to create a multipart upload on S3 : 
        {
            "message":"Missing credentials in config",
            "code":"CredentialsError",
            "time":"2015-07-28T22:59:10.763Z",
            "originalError":
                {
                    "message":"Could not load credentials from any providers",
                    "code":"CredentialsError",
                    "time":"2015-07-28T22:59:10.763Z",
                    "originalError":
                        {
                            "message": "Connection timed out after 1000ms",
                            "code":"TimeoutError",
                            "time":"2015-07-28T22:59:10.762Z"
                        }
                }
        }
```

To solve this I tried hard-coding the credentials using

```
AWS.config.update
```

Which doesn't seem to work as well.

What could the reason be for the error?

Thanks all!

Comment: Possibly a bug in s3-upload-stream or it's incompatible with the version of aws-sdk that you're using? Last change to the s3-upload-stream project looks like it was 8+ months ago so you might want to verify by downloading and using the relevant version of aws-sdk from about that date, for example https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/releases/tag/v2.0.23.

Comment: Ok! Makes a lot of sense to me! What would you suggest I use to stream files to S3 that will support a more recent version?

Comment: I would first try to get that stream library working and report any bugs via GitHub as it might be an easy fix (assuming it's actually a bug). I'd also look at what streaming capability aws-sdk has, for example I see what appears to be a file upload streaming example at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html (search for createReadStream).

Comment: actually there example seems very useful, but they don't seem to let you define the chuck sizes you want to use.

Comment: You can configure various options with the managed uploader, see "buffer 10 megabyte chunks and reduce concurrency down to 2" example at https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/javascript/post/Tx3EQZP53BODXWF/Announcing-the-Amazon-S3-Managed-Uploader-in-the-AWS-SDK-for-JavaScript. Not 100% sure this works with streaming but worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

Just incase this affects anyone else, setting the config before initialising AWS.S3() fixed it for me. 
`AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
var s3Stream = require('s3-upload-stream')(new AWS.S3());`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved mine by changing the user in my aws config file from a specific user to [default].

```
$nano .aws/credentials

[default]
aws_access_key_id = xyz
aws_secret_access_key = xyz
```